# Application area of toString() and valueOf() method

Tags: javascript

Can i know In what condition toString() and valueOf() methods gets invoked by js engine or when are these methods called?Also which method gets called fist?

Comment: this all depends on the context.  Can you give us some background on why you want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toString` converts a value to a string, `valueOf` converts it to a number.  Exactly which one is called depends on the context in which you're asking.

If javascript is expecting a string or trying to coerce the object to a string, it will use toString.  If it is expecting a number it will use valueOf.

the exception to this rule is that when a value has both a toString and a valueOf, it always calls valueOf.

```
var x = {
    toString: function(){
        return "x";
    },

    valueOf: function(){
        return 2;
    }

}


alert("String :"+x); //2

alert("Number :"+(0+x)); //2
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DsGKf/

So be careful about defining valueOf on things that you want to have act as strings.

Comment: can u give an example

Comment: string+2 should result an error

Comment: will 2 get converted to string

Comment: "string"+<something> will try to convert the second part to a string if possible.  If valueOf is defined it will use that value, otherwise it will use toString